# how to disable external pagination when data less than 10 rows in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

  var paginationOptions = {
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageSize: 25,
    sort: null
  };

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
    paginationPageSize: 25,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'gender', enableSorting: false },
      { name: 'company', enableSorting: false }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function(grid, sortColumns) {
        if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
          paginationOptions.sort = null;
        } else {
          paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
        }
        getPage();
      });
      gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
        paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
        paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
        getPage();
      });
    }
  };

  var getPage = function() {
    var url;
    switch(paginationOptions.sort) {
      case uiGridConstants.ASC:
        url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100_ASC.json';
        break;
      case uiGridConstants.DESC:
        url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100_DESC.json';
        break;
      default:
        url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json';
        break;
    }

    $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = 100;
      var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
    });
  };

  getPage();
}
]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code I am using external pagination in UI-grid.I want to disable pagination when data is less than 10 rows,if data more than 10 rows enable pagination.if possible display pagination outside the ui-grid.

Answer (score 2):

To use a custom pagination outside the grid, set `enablePaginationControls: false` in gridOptions.

You can then hide your outside pagination element, when data has less than 10 items.

Here is a [Plunker with live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dyS1gWwqDKz5LjqPXpYK?p=preview) that uses Bootstrap pagination directive.